# How to access first or second object in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, twig

I want to access the first object in my json, but the name changes for each product. For example: one product has `product.custom.6244816` and another one `product.custom.4298205`

This is what I have to acces `product.custom`

```
{{ product.custom | json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}
```

This is `product.custom`

```
{

"6244816": {

    "id": "6244816",

    "type": "select",

    "required": true,

    "max_chars": false,

    "title": "Selecteer voorzetplaat (verplicht)",

    "value": false

    }

}
```

How can I access `product.custom.6244816` (in this case) without typing the specific numbers behind `product.custom`?

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to do this in `twig` or `javascript` ???

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access it this way:
product.custom[0]

Comment: That returns `null` unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (which will give you array of keys in order) and then use the first key to access the value on that

```js
var result = {

"6244816": {

    "id": "6244816",

    "type": "select",

    "required": true,

    "max_chars": false,

    "title": "Selecteer voorzetplaat (verplicht)",

    "value": false

    }

}

console.log(result[Object.keys(result)[0]]);
```

`result` will `product.custom` in your example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in `twig`, there are two easy solutions

1. Use the filter `first`

The filter will return the first item of an array

2. Use the filter `keys`

The filter will return an (zero-based) indexed array of the keys of the array you've passed. This way u can defined which item u want to return from an associative array

```html
{% set foo = {"6000":{"name":"foo"},"7000":{"name":"bar"},"8000":{"name":"foobar"}} %}

{{ (foo|first).name }} {# out: foo #}
{{ foo[(foo|keys)[1]].name }} {# out: bar #}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/oy8x8e)